# Determing the position of a number in a java array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program that has an array of random numbers between 1 and 100.  The user is prompted to enter a number and then the program must see if the value is in the array. I'm assuming that as long as the user enters a number between 1 and 100 the number will be in the array.  If the number the user enters is in the array I need to output the position that number was in the array. How do you determine what position a number is in an array of randomly generated numbers?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab1
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] myList = new int [100];

    System.out.print(" Please enter a number betwen 1 and 100: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    if (num > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("No Match Found!");
    }   
        Random generator = new Random();
        int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(myList.length);


    if (num <= 100)
     {
         System.out.println(randomIndex);
         System.out.println("We found your number"+num+" at position YY in the array");
        }
    else;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either a) scan the whole array:

```
int index = 0;
boolean isNumberPresent = false;
while (index < array.length && !isNumberPresent) {
   if (array[index]==num) {
      isNumberPresent = true;
   }
   else {
     index++;
   }
}
// if isNumberPresent = true, then index now contains the number position, otherwise it will be = to array.length if the number is not there.
```

Or you can b) use a collection such as an arraylist instead of an array and use the .indexOf method.

Comment: Or c) smart using  ``Arrays#binarySearch``. This requires the array to be sorted.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman You are right, but given the question I assumed that OP isn't very experienced and therefore I wanted to keep it simple

Comment: @AndyBrown yeah, I guess we can get rid of the break to keep it even simpler.

Comment: The code above gives the entered number position 100 every time.

Comment: @BrianShook no it doesn't :) It gives 100 (i.e. the array length), if and only if the number you are searching is not present in the array! You can verify this as the variable isNumberPresent will be false in that case (see the code comment at the end of the snippet). Note that the code you posted DOES NOT guarantee that all numbers from 1 to 100 will be in the array! Some will be missing, some will be duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how:

```
int index = 0;
boolean noMatch = true;
for(int i=0; i<sizeofarray; i++) {
    if(array[i] == thenumberyouwanttomatch) {
        System.out.println("Number found at Index: " + i);
        index = i; //You can use this variable 'index' to access it's corresponding value outside the loop by using the term array[index]
        noMatch = false;
        break; //To Break from the loop and used only if there are no repetitions allowed
    }
}
if(noMatch) {
    System.out.println("Number not found at any index. Search failed");
}
```

Comment: you may add a ``break;`` in the case you found a match to skip the rest.

Comment: I don't like this - it doesn't make the "found" index available outside the search loop

Comment: @AndyBrown You better like it now ;)

Comment: It still doesn't make the matching element's index available outside the search loop.

Comment: @AndyBrown haha variable scope :P Edited.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make you search faster, why dont you Hashing/Hashmap. Other option is: since your random numbers are limited (1-100), you may want to use your number as index.

It is could be boolean array if you just want to know if the number is present, or a short/int array to know the count.

Comment: The bitmap is a valid suggestion, but the map isn't: you should rather use a Set in this case given that there is no value association with the key.

Comment: hmm.. The value I thought could be "count" of the random numbers.

Comment: In that case then yes. It's just that OP's sentence " I'm assuming that as long as the user enters a number between 1 and 100 the number will be in the array" made me think that each number is unique (otherwise the assumption is wrong), but its code doesn't guarantee it. :/